# enable activeForm validation on change Yii2

Tags: php, validation, yii2

I am trying to enable the validation process on change like this `'validateOnChange' => true` but without result. Also was trying to validate input when i click outside of it but it happens only on part of the forms e.g. in login form it is ok but in my custom form it is not working.
There is my form code:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
                                'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
                                'enableClientValidation' => false,
                                'validateOnBlur' => false,
                                'validateOnType' => false,
                                'validateOnChange' => true,
                                'options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]); ?>

                            <?= $form->field($modelRequest, 'phone')->textInput(['maxLength' => true, 'class' => 'product-request-input', 'placeholder' => 'телефон'])->label(false) ?>

                            <?= $form->field($modelRequest, 'email')->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'class' => 'product-request-input', 'placeholder' => 'email'])->label(false) ?>


                            <?= $form->field($modelRequest, 'subject')->activeTextInput(['maxLength' => true, 'class' => 'product-request-input', 'placeholder' => 'тема'])->label(false) ?>

                            <?= $form->field($modelRequest, 'question')->textarea(['rows' => 4, 'class' => 'product-request-input', 'placeholder' => 'съобщение'])->label(false) ?>

                              <?= Html::activeHiddenInput($modelRequest, 'product_id', ['value' => $product->id]) ?>

                            <?= '<img src="' . $_SESSION['captcha']['image_src'] . '" alt="CAPTCHA code" height="60" width="120" style="display: block; float: left;">' ?>

                            <?= $form->field($modelRequest, 'captcha_code')->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'class' => 'captcha-request-input', 'maxlength' => 5])->label(false) ?>

                            <?= Html::submitButton(Yii::t('app', 'app.send'), ['class' => 'request-send-btn']) ?>

                            <?= Html::resetButton(Yii::t('app', 'app.clear'), ['class' => 'request-send-btn']) ?>

                          <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

And my rules in model:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [[/*'name', */'subject', 'email', /*'phone', */'question'], 'required'],
            ['email', 'email'],
            [['phone', 'product_id','status'], 'integer'],
            [['question'], 'string'],
            [['dt'], 'safe'],
            [['name', 'subject'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
            [['email'], 'string', 'max' => 100],
            [['product_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Product::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['product_id' => 'id']],
        ];
    }
```

Seems like i missed something in the process.
Thank you in advance!

**EDIT:** Controller action:

```
public function actionProduct() {
        $first_step = Yii::$app->getRequest()->getQueryParam('first_step');
        $second_step = Yii::$app->getRequest()->getQueryParam('second_step');
        $product_step = Yii::$app->getRequest()->getQueryParam('product');
        $last = explode('-', $first_step);
        $id = end($last);
        $cat = Page::findOne($id);
        $lang = \frontend\models\Lang::getCurrent();
        $lisingChoice = new LisingChoice;
        $messageBro = '';
        $flagCaptcha = 0;
        $flagSend = 0;

        if (isset($cat) and $cat->url == $first_step) {
            $last = explode('-', $second_step);
            $id = end($last);
            $subcat = Page::findOne($id);
            $product = Product::findOne($id);
            $similar = Product::find()->joinWith('cats')->where('product_cat.product_id != :current_prod AND product_cat.page_id = :page1 AND product.quantity > 0', [':current_prod' => $product->id, ':page1' => $cat->id])->groupBy(['id'])->orderBy(new Expression('rand()'))->limit(12)->all();

            $allratings = ProductReview::find()->where('active=1 and product_id='.$id)->all();
            $relatedProducts = ProductRelated::find()->joinWith('relProduct')->where('product_related.main_product_id = :id AND product.active = 1', ['id' => $product->id])->orderBy('product.id')->all();
            if (Yii::$app->system->getGalleryTypeName() == 'fotorama') {
                Yii::$app->view->registerJsFile('/js/fotorama.js', ['position' => \yii\web\View::POS_END]);
                Yii::$app->view->registerCssFile("/css/fotorama.css", [
                    'depends' => [BootstrapAsset::className()],
                        ], 'css-theme');
            }
            if (isset($subcat) and $subcat->url == $second_step) {
                $last = explode('-', $product_step);
                $id = end($last);
                $product = Product::findOne($id);

                if ($product and $product->url == $product_step) {
                    Yii::$app->view->registerMetaTag([
                        'name' => 'description',
                        'content' => strip_tags(Yii::$app->OutData->showTXT($product->meta_description)),
                    ]);
                    Yii::$app->view->registerMetaTag([
                        'property' => 'og:image',
                        'content' => "http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $product->getImgWithoutKey(),
                    ]);

                    //$related = ProductRelated::find()->joinWith('relProduct')->where('product_related.main_product_id = :id AND product.active = 1', ['id' => $product->id])->orderBy(new Expression('rand()'))->limit(4)->all();
                    $related = Product::find()->joinWith('cats')->where('product_cat.product_id != :current_prod AND (product_cat.page_id = :page1 OR product_cat.page_id = :page2) AND product.quantity > 0 AND product.edit_mw = 1', [':current_prod' => $product->id, ':page1' => $cat->id, ':page2' => $subcat->id])->groupBy(['id'])->orderBy(new Expression('rand()'))->limit(5)->all();
                    $prodReviews = ProductReview::find()->where('active = 1 AND product_id =' . $product->id);
                    $dataProviderReviews = new ActiveDataProvider([
                        'query' => $prodReviews,
                        'pagination' => [
                            'pageSize' => 10,
                            'route' => Yii::$app->makeUrl->makeProductUrl($product->id),
                        ],
                        'sort' => [
                            'defaultOrder' => [
                                'dt' => SORT_DESC,
                            ]
                        ],
                    ]);
                    return $this->render('product', [
                                'product' => $product,
                                'subcat' => $subcat,
                                'cat' => $cat,
                                'allratings' => $allratings,
                                'similar' => $similar,
                                'related' => $related,
                                'dataProviderReviews' => $dataProviderReviews,
                                'lisingChoice' => $lisingChoice,
                                  'messageBro' => $messageBro,
                    ]);
                } else {
                    if (YII_DEBUG) {
                        $message = '#3<br>Controller: <strong>' . Yii::$app->controller->id . '</strong><br>Action: <strong>' . Yii::$app->controller->action->id . '</strong>';
                        return $this->render('error', [ 'message' => $message]);
                    } else {
                        throw new NotFoundHttpException(Yii::t('app', 'The requested page does not exist.'));
                    }
                }
            } elseif (isset($product) and $product->url == $second_step) {

                Yii::$app->view->registerMetaTag([
                    'name' => 'description',
                    'content' => strip_tags(Yii::$app->OutData->showTXT($product->meta_description)),
                ]);
                Yii::$app->view->registerMetaTag([
                    'property' => 'og:image',
                    'content' => "http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $product->getImgWithoutKey(),
                ]);
                $related = Product::find()->joinWith('cats')->joinWith('cats.page')->where('product_cat.product_id != :current_prod AND (product_cat.page_id = :page1 OR page.id_in = :page2)  AND product.quantity > 0 AND product.edit_mw = 1', [':current_prod' => $product->id, ':page1' => $cat->id, ':page2' => $cat->id])->groupBy(['id'])->orderBy(new Expression('rand()'))->limit(5)->all();
                $prodReviews = ProductReview::find()->where('active = 1 AND product_id =' . $product->id);
                $dataProviderReviews = new ActiveDataProvider([
                    'query' => $prodReviews,
                    'pagination' => [
                        'pageSize' => 10,
                        'route' => Yii::$app->makeUrl->makeProductUrl($product->id),
                    ],
                    'sort' => [
                        'defaultOrder' => [
                            'dt' => SORT_DESC,
                        ]
                    ],
                ]);

                $modelRequest = new RequestProduct();

                if ($modelRequest->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) ) {

                    if ($_SESSION['captcha']['code'] != $_POST['RequestProduct']['captcha_code']) {
                        $flagCaptcha = 1;
                    } else {
                        if ( $modelRequest->save() ) {
                                $flagSend = 1;
                                /*$modelRequest->name = $_POST['RequestProduct']['name'];*/
                                if(isset($_POST['RequestProduct']['phone']) && !empty($_POST['RequestProduct']['phone']))
                                {
                                    $modelRequest->phone = $_POST['RequestProduct']['phone'];
                                }
                                $modelRequest->email = $_POST['RequestProduct']['email'];
                                $modelRequest->question = $_POST['RequestProduct']['question'];
                                $modelRequest->subject = $_POST['RequestProduct']['subject'];
                                $modelRequest->product_id = $id;
                                $modelRequest->save(false);
                         }else{
                                $flagSend = 2;
                            }
                        }
                    }


                return $this->render('product', [
                            'product' => $product,
                            'subcat' => $subcat,
                            'cat' => $cat,
                            'related' => $related,
                            'dataProviderReviews' => $dataProviderReviews,
                            'lisingChoice' => $lisingChoice,
                            'flagCaptcha' => $flagCaptcha,
                            'modelRequest' => $modelRequest,
                            'relatedProducts' => $relatedProducts,
                            'similar' => $similar,
                            'allratings' => $allratings,
                            'flagSend' => $flagSend,
                ]);
            } else {
                if (YII_DEBUG) {
                    $message = '#2<br>Controller: <strong>' . Yii::$app->controller->id . '</strong><br>Action: <strong>' . Yii::$app->controller->action->id . '</strong>';
                    return $this->render('error', [ 'message' => $message]);
                } else {
                    throw new NotFoundHttpException(Yii::t('app', 'The requested page does not exist.'));
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (YII_DEBUG) {
                $message = '#1<br>Controller: <strong>' . Yii::$app->controller->id . '</strong><br>Action: <strong>' . Yii::$app->controller->action->id . '</strong>';
                return $this->render('error', [ 'message' => $message]);
            } else {
                throw new NotFoundHttpException(Yii::t('app', 'The requested page does not exist.'));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: perhaps `'validationUrl' => [Yii::$app->request->pathInfo],` in activeForm config

Comment: Without change.

Comment: What's the symptoms of 'not working'? Is there any ajax request on change? Show your controller code.

Comment: When i click the send button it is validating the form after reloading the page. I am trying to each input when i unfocus it. Excuse me if i can't explain it very well.